# Find the best medical pathway

Tags: r, data-analysis

From hospital data, I know what all are various procedures done for a particular treatment by different doctors and for different patient demographics. Now I want to analyze these various paths and understand which is the best in terms of cost. When I say best it doesn't mean the one with minimum cost is best. Should find out the path followed by majority doctors and out of which is the least costly. My data is:

```
Doctor Procedure1 Procedure2 Procedure3 Procedure4 Procedure5 Charge
   111          1          2          3          4          5    200
   222          1          4          7          4          9    185
   333          2          3          5          1          9    250
   444          1          2          3          4          6    210
   222          1          2          3          4          6    210
```

I want to know of all these paths which one is the best.

Comment: You need to be way more specific when asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each path `dd` shows its `Count` (i.e. the number of rows having that path). `dd` is sorted in descending order of `Count` and ascending order of `Charge`. At the end we show the least expensive path(s) for each `Count` sorted in descending order of `Count`.

```
dd <- aggregate(list(Count = 1:nrow(DF)), DF[-1], length)
dd <- dd[order(-dd$Count, dd$Charge), ]
dd2 <- dd[ave(dd$Charge, dd$Count, FUN = function(x) x == x[1]) == 1, ]
```

giving:

```
> dd2
  Procedure1 Procedure2 Procedure3 Procedure4 Procedure5 Charge Count
3          1          2          3          4          6    210     2
1          1          4          7          4          9    185     1
```

That is, among those paths used twice 12346 is the least costly with a Charge of 210 and among those paths used once 14749 is the least costly with a Charge of 185.  You can now assess the trade-off between Count and Charge.  (To look at the counts for all paths look at `dd` contains one row per path with its `Count` sorted by `Count` and `Charge`.)

One other thing you could do would be to remove dominated rows.  That is if any row has higher Count and lower Charge than the current row then we can remove the current row.  In this example there are no dominated rows but in case there could be this would remove them:

```
is_dom <- function(r, DF) with(DF, any(Count[-r] > Count[r] & Charge[-r] < Charge[r]))
dominated <- sapply(1:nrow(dd2), is_dom, dd2)
dd3 <- dd2[!dominated, ]
```

**Note:** The input in reproducible form is:

```
DF <-
structure(list(Doctor = c(111L, 222L, 333L, 444L, 222L), Procedure1 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Procedure2 = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L), Procedure3 = c(3L, 
7L, 5L, 3L, 3L), Procedure4 = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L), Procedure5 = c(5L, 
9L, 9L, 6L, 6L), Charge = c(200L, 185L, 250L, 210L, 210L)), .Names = c("Doctor", 
"Procedure1", "Procedure2", "Procedure3", "Procedure4", "Procedure5", 
"Charge"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

**Update:** Simplify.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for...

Comment: Have added some optional code to remove dominated rows (`dd3`).  Doesn't change the example but maybe for your real data it can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the change... i had achieved it via another code but yours is easy and simple

Answer (score 0):

The following process will get unique procedure combinations and will calculate how popular they are (i.e. number of rows) and how much they cost on average:

```
library(dplyr)

dt = read.table(text = "
Doctor    Procedure1   Procedure2   Procedure3   Procedure4   Procedure5   Charge
111         1               2            3            4           5           200
222         1               4            7            4           9           185
333         2               3            5            1           9           250
444         1               2            3            4           6           210
222         1               2            3            4           6           210
", header=T)

dt %>%
  group_by(Procedure1,Procedure2,Procedure3,Procedure4,Procedure5) %>%   # group by those 5 steps / procedures
  summarise(NumRows = n(),                                               # count how many rows they have
            AvgCharge = mean(Charge)) %>%                                # calculate average of charge
  ungroup() %>%                                                           
  arrange(desc(NumRows))                                                 # order by popularity

# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   Procedure1 Procedure2 Procedure3 Procedure4 Procedure5 NumRows AvgCharge
#        <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>   <int>     <dbl>
# 1          1          2          3          4          6       2       210
# 2          1          2          3          4          5       1       200
# 3          1          4          7          4          9       1       185
# 4          2          3          5          1          9       1       250
```

You should think how to pick the most popular ones. Is it top X? Is it the ones that represent Y% of the rows / doctors?
Then you should consider doing some statistical comparison of your average values instead of just picking the lowest one.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this, when combined with the previous comment, solves what I had in mind.